# Convert Cardinal to IUnknow

Tags: delphi, com, vb6, ole

I am working on adoption of Visual Basic code into Delphi code right now.

What I have:

```
   // prepare query
   with oleClipboardFormat do
   begin
     cfFormat := CF_FileContents;
     ptd := nil;
     dwAspect := DVASPECT_CONTENT;
     lindex := Index;
     tymed := TYMED_ISTREAM or TYMED_ISTORAGE;
   end;

   // query data
   data.GetData(oleClipboardFormat, oleMedium)
```

The field `oleMedium.hGlobal` (type of variable is `Cardinal`) contains a reference to `IStorage` interface.

How should I cast `oleMedium.hGlobal` to `IStorage`?

There is some kind of black magic in the VB sources I am translating right now. The author of the code uses following visual basic function to cast pointers to interfaces...

```
Private Function ResolvePointer(ByVal PtrObj As Long) As stdole.IUnknown
Dim oUnk As stdole.IUnknown

' Get an uncounted reference
' to the IUnknown interface
MoveMemory oUnk, PtrObj, 4&

' Get a counted reference
Set ResolvePointer = oUnk

' Release the uncounted reference
MoveMemory oUnk, 0&, 4&

End Function
```

Comment: Next time, please remember to include **variable declarations** with your code. I had to do a bit of searching before I figured out what `GetData` was and what its argument types were.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `oleMedium` variable is declared as a `TStgMedium`. It has an `hGlobal` field, but it *also* has a `stg` field, which is of type `Pointer`. Use that field, and type-cast it to `IStorage` when you need to use the interface:

```
IStorage(oleMedium.stg)
```

Your VB author didn't have type-casting at his or her disposal, so the code copied memory from one variable to another.

Comment: Thank you for your time. I just noticed that he just copiing addres of an interface.